# Was the earth split by the sound in 1 Kings 1:40?

Tags: 1-kings

1 Kings 1:40
New International Version

> And all the people went up after him, playing pipes and rejoicing greatly, so that the ground **shook** with the sound.

Berean Study Bible

> All the people followed him, playing flutes and rejoicing with such a great joy that the earth was **split** by the sound.

Which version is more accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the literal meaning of the word בָּקַע is to cleave, break open or through.  However, we must remind ourselves that Hebrew has no abstract nouns and must use verbal-nouns to describe feelings and emotions.

For example, אַף is nostril, or nose.  However, it is often (correctly) translated "anger" which means that a person who is angry is described as "nosing" - ie, breathing heavily.

The same is true in other circumstances.  The Hebrew is highly idiomatic and so translating some words literally makes no sense.  1 Kings 1:40 is a good example of this.  Thus, I would render 1 Kings 1:40 as either:

- ... the earth seemed to burst open with their joyful sound,

or,

- the earth shook with their joyful sound

Both of these idiomatic renderings have plenty of support among the many versions available.  BDB lists 1 Kings 1:40 as "hyperbolic" supporting the above non-literal understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning is indeed "split," not "shook."

You can find the Hebrew of the verse here:

http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a01.htm#40

This is the part you're looking for:

וַתִּבָּקַע הָאָרֶץ

That first word, v'tibbaqa`, has a root of bq`, so we can look it up in Brown Driver Briggs by that:

https://archive.org/details/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft/page/130/mode/2up?view=theater

You can see the entry in the rightmost column; it's the last major entry in that column.  It starts with the Qal.  We follow to the next page...

https://archive.org/details/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft/page/132/mode/2up?view=theater

...to see the Niphal, which is used in this verse, and you can see that it means "be cleft, rent open" or "to burst open" and it even includes a reference to this very verse, "1 K 1^40".

They note that it's hyperbole.  But technically it could mean that the earth was actually split open.

Here you can see how a wide variety of translations render it:

https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/1%20Kings%201:40